# How can I migrate messages from gmail to dovecot?

Tags: linux, dovecot

How do I import .mbox files from Gmail takeout to a dovecot Maildir?

Comment: Can always brute-force it: install Thunderbird on a client, log into the IMAP account you want them to go into, and then import them all into Thunderbird which will then push them all into the server via IMAP...